# Bluetooth is not working in Ubuntu 19.10 on HP laptop

Tags: bluetooth

Bluetooth is not displaying in `rfkill` list.

[image: terminal screenshot]

```
aditya@aditya-HP-Laptop-15q-dy0xxx:~$ rfkill list
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
aditya@aditya-HP-Laptop-15q-dy0xxx:~$
```

[image]

My bluetooth is not working. Please help me out on the resolution.

In Settings → Bluetooth, it says:

> #### No Bluetooth Found
>
> Plug in a dongle to use Bluetooth.

[image: settings screenshot]