# Realtek Bluetooth on HP Laptop, Xubuntu 19.10 no longer working

Tags: drivers, kernel, bluetooth, laptop, 19.10

The Bluetooth support on my **HP 14-ck0065st** laptop seems to have vanished into thin air. It did work, once upon a time, under Xubuntu 18.04, but upgrading to 19.10 seems to have borked it.

The failure mode is similar to the question posted [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1196255/bluetooth-is-not-working-in-ubuntu-19-10-on-hp-laptop).

`rfkill list all` produces

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
```

(Note: I have the wireless turned off as I am currently using a wired connection - wireless itself works fine)

Perhaps relevant `dmesg` output:

```
[   19.799152] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[   19.799172] NET: Registered protocol family 31
[   19.799173] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   19.799176] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   19.799178] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   19.799181] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   20.636136] btrtl: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
[   20.636137] btrtl: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
[   20.636138] btrtl: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
[   20.636173] btrtl: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
[   20.806235] btusb: Unknown symbol btrtl_shutdown_realtek (err -2)
[   20.821236] btusb: Unknown symbol btrtl_shutdown_realtek (err -2)
[   20.837193] btusb: Unknown symbol btrtl_shutdown_realtek (err -2)
[   20.853211] btusb: Unknown symbol btrtl_shutdown_realtek (err -2)
[   20.877235] btusb: Unknown symbol btrtl_shutdown_realtek (err -2)
[   20.897154] btusb: Unknown symbol btrtl_shutdown_realtek (err -2)
[   22.202669] rtl8723de: Using firmware rtlwifi/rtl8723defw.bin
[   22.205982] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'rtl_rc'
[   22.206298] rtlwifi: rtlwifi: wireless switch is on
[   22.614202] wl: module license 'MIXED/Proprietary' taints kernel.
[   22.614203] Disabling lock debugging due to kernel taint
[   22.728296] rtl8723de 0000:02:00.0 wlp2s0: renamed from wlan0
[   27.989814] checking generic (a0000000 300000) vs hw (a0000000 10000000)
```

Other perhaps relevant information:

```
lspci -knn | grep Net -A2; lsusb
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723DE 802.11b/g/n PCIe Adapter [10ec:d723]
        Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8723DE 802.11b/g/n PCIe Adapter [103c:8319]
        Kernel driver in use: rtl8723de
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:b009 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 802.11n WLAN Adapter
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 05c8:03c7 Cheng Uei Precision Industry Co., Ltd (Foxlink) HP TrueVision HD Camera
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0a5c:21e8 Broadcom Corp. BCM20702A0 Bluetooth 4.0
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

I've gone through all the various machinations with replacing the drivers from [rtlwifi_new](https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new) to no avail.

I do note that the `Unknown symbol btrtl_shutdown_realtek` message appears to be related to a kernel configuration item `CONFIG_BT_RTL` being set to **m** (see [here](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/drivers/bluetooth/btrtl.h)). I may try setting it to **y** and rebuilding, just to see if that makes any difference.

I suppose my next step, barring someone helping me with a less painful fix, is to revert back to 18.04 with a fresh install, which I'd like to avoid since I have several hundred gigs of data on the laptop that I'd rather not have to offload and restore.

If I've left anything out above, please let me know and I shall provide forthwith.  Or even fiftwith.  Whichever is faster.

Comment: This is way too broad. 20.04 is off-topic. Please pick Realtek or Broadcom device for the question.

Comment: Okay, I've elided the offending material. I included it because I thought that the extra information might be useful to diagnose the issue. Please accept my abject apologies for any offense given.

Comment: You've installed some out-of-tree bluetooth kernel module that is not loading becuase of Secure boot enabled in BIOS. Or it is not compatible with the kernel. I suggest to remove it.

Comment: Just checked, secure boot is not enabled.  In fact, it's greyed out in the choices for some reason.

Comment: Then the module is incompatible. What did you install? Please show `dkms status`. I suspect you've installed my backport.

Comment: I installed items from rtlwifi_new as describe above. I figured the unmentionalble upgrade would have cleaned whatever I'd done but perhaps there's still cruft left. If there's a way to revert, I'd be happy to learn it.

Comment: rtlwifi_new doesn't contain `btrtl`. On 19.10 you don't need it anyway.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103546/discussion-between-teakwood-j-overclutch-and-pilot6).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix is to remove the 3rd party `btrtl` module by

```
sudo dkms remove btrtl-rtl8723de/0.2 --all
```

All other `dkms` modules can be removed to clean all up.

The Realtek `rtl8723de` is fully supported by 5.3+ kernels and they are not needed any more.

Comment: For the record, after all these machinations, Bluetooth worked for about five minutes and then stopped.  And, to top it off, wireless disappeared from the system too.  I've decided to punt, back up my home directory, scrub it, and fall back to 18.04, which worked consistently. Lesson learned: stay off the leading edge.

Comment: That must be some 20.04 issue ;-)

Comment: Following up, I scrubbed the system clean, installed 18.04, installed the rtlwifi_new drivers, and restored my home directory. Now all is in working order. Thanx to Pilot6 for their help on this.  I suspect that in my blundering around to get Bluetooth working, I managed to tromp on one or more critical operating system features. Lessons learned:(1) be sure understand what you're doing when your doing it, (2) keep careful notes, and (3) stay away from HP laptops -- I've had nothing but headaches with them.